# Cannot create a temporary stage object in a Snowflake stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The below stored procedure execution returns the error message '**Stored procedure execution error: Unsupported statement type 'temporary STAGE**'.' Removing the keyword 'temporary' from the stored procedure definition solves the problem and it can be executed without any error.

How is it possible ? As per its documentation, Snowflake supports the creation of temporary stage.
On top of that, the same SQL statement works properly once it is executed outside a stored procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "TEST_TEMP_STAGE"()
RETURNS FLOAT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
STRICT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS $$
    var req='create  temporary stage my_temp_stage;'
    snowflake.createStatement( { sqlText: req } ).execute();
    return 0;
$$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define your procedure as "EXECUTE AS CALLER" to be  able to create a temporary stage inside your stored procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "TEST_TEMP_STAGE"()
RETURNS FLOAT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
STRICT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS $$
    var req='create temporary stage my_temp_stage;'
    snowflake.createStatement( { sqlText: req } ).execute();
    return 0;
$$
;

call TEST_TEMP_STAGE();
```

Comment: Many thanks, it works now. But do you know why you should execute it as caller ? Creating a temporary table inside a stored procedure does not require to run the stored procedure as caller. So why should it be the case for stage objects ?

Comment: It's a security related restriction. It's not documented well, but in short, Snowflake stored procedure which is executed as owner, should not let you handle anything related to user session. Temporary table seems like a missed point - IMO.